# Magento 2 - Error with new custom module - Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #1

Tags: magento2, module, error

Does anyone have any idea what this error is when running this command in magento 2: setup:upgrade for a custom module?

Here is the error:

```
Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #1 [ <required> Magento\Cms\Setup\PageSetupFactory $pageSetupFactory ] of ViewSonic\MetaRobots\Setup\Patch\Data\AddMetaRobotsAttribute class
```

Here is the coding:

```
 <?php
namespace ViewSonic\MetaRobots\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Cms\Setup\PageSetup;
use Magento\Cms\Setup\PageSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchVersionInterface;

class AddMetaRobotsAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchVersionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var PageSetupFactory
     */
    private $pageSetupFactory;

    /**
     * AddMetaRobotsAttribute constructor.
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param PageSetupFactory $pageSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        PageSetupFactory $pageSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->pageSetupFactory = $pageSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var PageSetup $pageSetup */
        $pageSetup = $this->pageSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $pageSetup->addAttribute(
            'page',
            'meta_robots',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Meta Robots',
                'input' => 'select',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 70,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'default' => '',
                'source' => ''
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getVersion()
    {
        return '2.4.3';
    }
}
```

Any help would be so appreciated. Thanks in advanced

Comment: can you please post AddMetaRobotsAttribute file ?

Comment: as per error, you need to pass Magento\Cms\Setup\PageSetupFactory; this in to AddMetaRobotsAttribute this file

Comment: @RonakRathod - added the file. Thank you